# Overriding abstract generic method in Java

Tags: java, generics, abstract, overriding

**Problem outline**

I'm generifying the better part of my current project's base and I had an idea that I decided to test regarding overriding an abstract method. Here are my test classes in Java:

```
public abstract class Base {

    public abstract <T extends Base> T test();

}
```

First implementation:

```
public class Inheritor extends Base {

    @Override
    public Inheritor test() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Second implementation:

```
public class Inheritor2 extends Base {

    @Override
    public <T extends Base> T test() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Question 1**

Why does it compile? I admit I had high hopes it would be legal, since it makes the contract not only ensure it returns something that does extend Base, but is more specialized already (so that I don't need to cast the result to my specialized class somewhere later).

All sounds nice but do I *really* fulfill the contract that the base class forces me into? My overriden implementation in `Inheritor` loses certain layer of genericness doesn't it? My implementation of this method in `Inheritor` doesn't ever return an instance of `Inheritor2`, possibility of which the abstract method seemed to enforce (as both extend `Base`).

I would like pointing to some excerpt from documentation. My guess is it has something to do with type erasure, would be nice if someone mentioned it's accuracy in his/her answer.

**Question 2**

Does this procedure have a formal name other than one I stated in the title?

**Question 3**

Is this possible in C#? Colleague's scratch test seemed to fail on compilation. Is there then a difference in approach to generic abstract method overriding?

Comment: What is question 1? 2. It's overriding a method. 3. I believe Alan Turing says yes.

Comment: If this is called overriding a method and the above example doesn't seem to compile in C#, it formally means C# does not support overriding methods.

Comment: Java is not C#. And yes, in Java this is [overriding a method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1).

Comment: That leaves the question whether it's possible to reproduce in C# and the first question (mostly about losing genericness)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the technicalities.

Concerning [overriding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1):

> An instance method `mC` declared in or inherited by class `C`, overrides
>   from `C` another method `mA` declared in class `A`, iff all of the following
>   are true:
>
> - `A` is a superclass of `C`.
> - `C` does not inherit `mA`.
> - The signature of `mC` is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of `mA`.
> - One of the following is true:
>
>   - `mA` is `public`.
>   - [...]

In your case, `A` is `Base` and `C` is `Inheritor`, `Base#test()` is `mA` and `Inheritor#test()` is `mC`.

`mC` is a subsignature of `mA` [because](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)

> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a
>   method m2 if either:
>   - m2 has the same signature as m1, or
>   - **the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.**

The erasure of `mA` is

```
public abstract Base test()
```

and `mC`

```
public Inheritor test()
```

is a subsignature. [What about the return type?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3)

> If a method declaration `d1` with return type `R1` overrides or hides the
>   declaration of another method `d2` with return type `R2`, then `d1` must be
>   [return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5) for `d2`, or a compile-time error
>   occurs.

Following the `return-type-substitutable`, we see

> If R1 is a reference type then one of the following is true:
>
> - `R1` can be converted to a subtype of `R2` by unchecked conversion (§5.1.9).

`Inheritor` is a subtype of `T extends Base` through unchecked conversion, so we're all good (though you should have gotten a warning from your compiler).

So to answer your questions:

1. It compiles because of the rules declared in the Java Language Specification.
2. It's called overriding.
3. I don't have a full answer for you, but C# doesn't seem to have type erasure, so these rules wouldn't apply.

---

The dangers of unchecked conversion would allow you to do

```
class Inheritor extends Base {
    @Override
    public Inheritor test() {
        return new Inheritor();
    }
}
```

and then

```
Base ref = new Inheritor();
Inheritor2 wrong = ref.<Inheritor2>test();
```

which would cause a `ClassCastException` at runtime. Use it at your own risk.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you for pointing me to the rule about return-type-substitutability, this is exactly what I wanted to get to know. Also this being an unchecked conversion quite explains why IntelliJ IDEA is grumpy about what I did, thank you for an example of misuse. Also didn't know C# didn't have type erasure which is why this happened. Thanks for a really well documented answer!

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you why it should work - [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

The question to ask is, if you replace Base with Inheritor, or Inheritor2, will all the consumers continue to work without negative consequences?  If they expect anything that extends Base from `test`, then swapping Inheritor2 with Inheritor, or vice versa, will be fine from the perspective a consumer.  So, the compiler ought to allow it.

You do really fulfill the contract, which says any subtype of `Base` can be returned.  Any subtype can be one subtype, a random subtype, etc.

Like the commenter Elliott, I believe it's just called overriding a method.

Here's a similar implementation in C# but with generics on the class level.

```
    public abstract class Base<Type>
        where Type : Base<Type>
    {
        public abstract Type test();
    }

    public class Inheritor:Base<Inheritor>
    {
        public override Inheritor test()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Inheritor2<Type> : Base<Type>
        where Type : Base<Type>
    {
        public override Type test()
        {
            return default(Type);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your C# example places the type parameter at the class level rather than the method level. I would think that makes a big difference.

Comment: Quite true . . . let me see if I can figure out how to do it on the method level.

Comment: Thought the contract said : "You should return exactly what I can return and nothing less", which it doesn't because the first implementation is much less generic. Guess that's where the confusion came from. I am still interested in that C# version though.